# Dynamic opening hours for schema.org

Tags: php, schema.org

I am new to this forum, and wanted to ask for help. Recently I had to implement schema.org/LocalBusiness microdata in to group of websites, but the problem is that I need to add this dynamically. Everything was quite easy until the opening hours came out.
So the way that schema wants the hours to be displayed is:

```
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">Mon-Sat 11am - 2:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Th 17:00-21:30">Mon-Thu 5pm - 9:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00">Fri-Sat 5pm - 10:00pm
```

I managed only to display the opening hours for each day separately, but I need to display them as the code above.

What I did to try this was to fetch the data from my opening hours form in to an array. For example:

```
$days = array('mo' => '13:00-20:00',
        'tu' => '13:00-20:00',
        'we' => '13:00-20:00',
        'th' => '11:00-18:00',
        'fr' => '11:00-18:00',
        'sa' => '15:00-22:00',
        'su' => '13:00-20:00',);
```

The result that I need to display from this array is:

```
<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-We 13:00-20:00">Mon-We 13:00-20:00
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Th-Fr 11:00-18:00">Th-Fr 11:00-18:00
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Sa 15:00-22:00">Sat 15:00-22:00
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Su 13:00-20:00">Sun 13:00-20:00
```

and tried loop this array with many ifs inside. So, probably most of you can figure out that like this I won't achieve nothing. Here is my code. I haven't tested this code because i can't figure out how to retrieve $last_key's_value_equal. Hope anyone can understand me because my explanations aren't very good, but if someone can help I will be more than grateful.

```
foreach($day as $key=>$value){
    if($value == next($day)){
        if($value == next($day)){
            if($value == next($day)){
                if($value == next($day)){
                    if($value == next($day)){
                        if($value == next($day)){
                        $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
                        }else{
                        $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
                        }
                    }else{
                    $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
                    }
                $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
                }else{
                $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
                }
            $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
            }else{
            $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
            }
        $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
        }else{
        $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
        }
    $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
    else{
    $opening_hours .= $key.'-'.$last_key's_value_equal.' '.$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep an array of contiguous groups. As you iterate through your `$days`, check if the last item had the same hours. If yes, add the day to the same group; if not, create a new group.

E.g., this function, when applied to your `$days` array:

```php
function group_contiguous_values($arr) {
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $lastidx = count($groups)-1;
        if (isset($groups[$lastidx][$v])) {
            $groups[$lastidx][$v][] = $k;
        } else {
            $groups[] = array($v => array($k));
        }
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

Will produce this result:

```php
array(
  array('13:00-20:00' => array('mo', 'tu', 'we')),
  array('11:00-18:00' => array('th', 'fr')),
  array('15:00-22:00' => array('sa')),
  array('13:00-20:00' => array('su')),
);
```

From there it's just a matter of elbow grease to get the human-readable version you want. This code will take care of the itemprop *value*:

```php
$time_templ = '<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="%s %s">%s %s</time>'."\n";

foreach ($business_hours as $group) {
    list($hours, $days) = each($group);
    list($open, $close) = explode('-', $hours, 2);
    $firstday = ucfirst($days[0]);
    $lastday = (count($days)>1) ? ucfirst(end($days)) : null;
    $meta_days = $firstday;
    if ($lastday) {
        $meta_days .= "-$lastday";
    }
    $meta_hours = $hours;

    printf($time_templ, $meta_days, $meta_hours, $meta_days, $meta_hours);
}
```

Which prints:

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-We 13:00-20:00">Mo-We 13:00-20:00</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Th-Fr 11:00-18:00">Th-Fr 11:00-18:00</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sa 15:00-22:00">Sa 15:00-22:00</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Su 13:00-20:00">Su 13:00-20:00</time>
```

Comment: You are awesome!!! It works fine!!! Even if I can't understand exactly how this code works I will figure it out soon or late. But it works! This is the most important!

Comment: How can I add 2 date ranges per day like Facebook pages hours. Example: add 2 date ranges for monday like this: array('mo' => '08:00-13:00', '14:00-18:00'). It should display Sa 08:00-13:00 and 14:00-18:00. Is there a library for this? Thanks!